# Excel 2010 AddPicture functionality changed?

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2010

Me again.

In Excel 2003, we're using some VBA to automate adding a picture to a worksheet.

The call, in a nutshell, is:

```
Dim Pic as Object
Dim filePath as String
.
.
.
Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filePath)
```

... where filePath gets updated with an appropriate file name by the calling macro.

In Excel 2003, this embeds the picture in the workbook, which allows you to save it, reopen it, move it to another folder, email it, etc. etc. and the pictures stay put.

In Excel 2010, this macro appears to work beautifully, until you save, close and reload the .xlsx workbook. Then, you see something like this:

[image: damn Excel 2010...]

Somehow, the functionality has changed from embedding an image to linking to it.

I cannot find any documentation that details this major change in behaviour. Has anyone else noticed this change in operation? Is there another VBA call I can use to actually embed the picture, as opposed to statically linking to it?